# Why are my popup page functions not working?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP calendar application that presents a schedule in table form. Each cell is selectable and has the following Jquery popup code behind it:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
if (roleID > 2)
{
    window.open("","popUpForm","height=550,width=1050,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=100,status=no,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,right=300,top=100");
    $('.jobTime').submit();
}
```

That works fine and presents a form called newJobForm.php in the popup window. The user enters selected times...and submits. If there is a conflict with the attempted schedule the window popup is closed and the form is reopened with with conflict information:

```
else
{
    $userSTime = new DateTime($params[0]);
    $userSTime = date_format($userSTime,'m/d/Y h:i a');
    $userETime = new DateTime($params[1]);
    $userETime = date_format($userETime,'m/d/Y h:i a');     
    $_SESSION['jbNum'] = $params[2];
    $_SESSION['asset'] = $params[4];
    $_SESSION['userSTime'] = $userSTime;
    $_SESSION['userETime'] = $userETime;
    $_SESSION['userDesc'] = trim($params[3]);
    $_SESSION['conJbNum'] = $msg['JobNum'];
    $_SESSION['conSTime'] = date_format($msg['StartTime'], 'm/d/Y h:i a');
    $_SESSION['conETime'] = date_format($msg['EndTime'], 'm/d/Y h:i a');
    $_SESSION['dueDate'] = $params[5];
    $_SESSION['comment'] = $params[6];
    $_SESSION['destination'] = $params[7];
    $_SESSION['jStat'] = $params[8];
    $_SESSION['ujob'] = $params[9];


    if ($_SESSION['recurring'] == 'n')
    {
        echo '<script>window.open("../forms/newJobForm.php","popUpForm","height=550,width=900,status=yes, scrollbars=1, toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");</script>';
        windowClose();      
        exit;
    }
```

This part works fine if the user makes the right corrections. However, if the user makes another scheduling error the form will close and redisplay information. At this point the close function quits working and the original parent page doesn't refresh. The parent page not refreshing I kind of understand, but the close function is simply that 'close'.

```
function windowClose()
{
    echo "<script>window.close()</script>";
}
```

what is going wrong? I can't really post the whole code because there is about 1000 lines of code, give or take... How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: _“If there is a conflict with the attempted schedule the window popup is closed and the form is reopened with with conflict information”_ – so the form is “reopened” in another _popup_ with the same window name again? Why would you even do that – instead of just displaying the form in the _same_ popup window again …?

Comment: When the input is processed it is checked against a database and refreshing the page brings up a resend confirmation message. The users of the application find that clicking an extra button an extra step and that means more time and therefore a waste of time. Here, a waste of time is unacceptable.

Comment: Then don’t _refresh_ the page, just have the same form _displayed_ again in the server’s response to the validation error …

Comment: Forgive me but I don't know if I understand the logic of your answer. If the user puts information in and clicks submit, it hits the server and the server responds by displaying the conflict. If the user enters new information and clicks submit, it hits the server and the server responds with new conflict information. How can I change the information without refreshing/reloading the page? I am a php developer, so the front end work is not my strong suit. On a failed attempt the popup no longer belongs to the parent page and the schedule page no longer auto reloads with the new data.

Comment: Of course the popup does not belong to the parent page any more if you open _another_ popup from within the first popup – that _second_ popup would belong to the first popup. That’s why I suggested displaying the form with the error information in the _same_ popup window again.

Comment: Agreed and done in said fashion. This still does not explain why the close function stops working after two failed attempts. Its a simple hard coded statement that only works within the first two tries?

Comment: So it works after the first failed attempt - meaning, form is loaded into the popup, submitted once, fails, displayed again, validates this time, and then can be closed _and_ reload the parent window? If anything, I would have expected it to fail after the first failed attempt already (because in some browsers navigating to a new resource inside a popup does indeed detach it from its parent).

Comment: How about another appoach then: Instead of the popup, use an `iframe` that you display inside resp. over the parent page content, and load your form and its failure messages/re-displays into that. You can submit your form over as many “fail” cycles as you want without affecting the parent page, and you will also not lose the “connection” with the parent as might happen with popups. And “closing” it should be no problem either – just set it to `display:none` or remove it from the parent document’s DOM, and it’s gone … (plus it will not get caught in a popup blocker either)

Comment: Or if you reload the parent page (which you can access simply using the reserved window instance name `top`) anyway after success, the iframe will be gone then anyway.

Comment: I am going to give it a shot. Sounds about right. Thanks for the patience and I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe I was able to solve this particular problem with the following modifications to my application. In my file where I check the user input for any conflicts with existing entries I changed:

```
if ($_SESSION['recurring'] == 'n')
    {
        echo '<script>window.open("../forms/newJobForm.php","popUpForm","height=550,width=900,status=yes, scrollbars=1, toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");</script>';
        windowClose();      
        exit;
    }
```

to:

```
if ($_SESSION['recurring'] == 'n')
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=../forms/newJobForm.php' target = '_SELF'/>";       
    exit;
}
```

Which simply refreshes the original form with the new conflict (if there is a conflict) information, or allows the user to submit or cancel the attempted action regardless of how many times they try. And to the form its self I added the following javascript make sure the user's actions refresh the parent page:

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent() 
{
    window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
}
```

And the function that creates the initial popup was slightly modified like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
if (roleID > 2)
{
    popUpForm = window.open("","popUpForm","height=550,width=1050,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=100,status=no,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,right=300,top=100");
    $('.jobTime').submit();
}
```

I hope others will find this useful.